# How do you reproduce the text displayed in a TreeViewItem while using a ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, controltemplate, treeviewitem

I am attempting to modify a TreeView to display the TreeViewItem values above and below their child items, such that:

```
foo
|bar
||baz
|biz
```

would become

```
foo
|bar
||baz
| baz
|bar
|biz
 biz
foo
```

A trimmed representation of the current control template is provided below, provided with no guarantee that this snippet compiles:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
  <Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19"
                          Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    ClickMode="Press"/>
      <Border Name="Bd"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                          ContentSource="Header"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
      </Border>
      <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
      <TextBlock Text="Some Binding Goes Here"
                 Grid.Row="2"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

The repeated entries would not have children, it would just be the display value. Thus far I can modify the TreeView ContainerStyle using a ControlTemplate to insert a TextBlock at the appropriate place in the visual tree. What data binding should be used in order to fetch the appropriate display value?

Comment: Where are the values coming from in regards to what you are wanting to bind it to..? do you have any code that you have actually tried on your own yet..?

Comment: The TreeView is binding to a XmlDocument and is being populated by a HierarchicalDataTemplate. I will reproduce part of the control template above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a `ContentPresenter` again?

```
<ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"
                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                  Grid.Row="2"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

Comment: But what content source would you use? The header is fixed for the entire TreeView isn't it?

Comment: No, each TreeViewItem has its own header. It is a label, like foo/bar/biz or an image too if you want. With the code above you simply duplicate this header content on a chosen place within the template. Try it out!

Comment: I realized that was what you were getting at in the shower this morning. Thank you, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: This came down to a misunderstanding of how a TreeViewItem is rendered. The value that you are setting in the ItemsTemplate is the Header and the ItemsPresenter is the body of the HeaderedContentControl. The naming conventions they use for the properties do nothing to help with this.